# SQL query for vice versa case

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have similar table structure as shown below

[image]

Now here I want write a **query** (*without using inner query*) and find all those number who have condition like
(value 1 = A and value 2 = B) and (value 1 = B and value 2 = A).

Means Kind of vice versa case where a number is having both value1 and value2 having A and B.

Thus for the given case my **query** output would be 1  and 4.

Comment: What is your PRIMARY KEY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to repeat the duplicate rows, following should work:

```
mysql> select a.* from tbl_so_q23676640 a
    ->  join tbl_so_q23676640 b
    ->  on a.v1 = b.v2 and a.v2 = b.v1
    -> where a.n=b.n
    -> group by a.n, a.v1, a.v2
    -> ;
+------+------+------+
| n    | v1   | v2   |
+------+------+------+
|    1 | a    | b    |
|    1 | b    | a    |
|    4 | a    | b    |
|    4 | b    | a    |
+------+------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try this query:

```
select t1.NUMBER from mytable t1
join mytable t2 on t1.NUMBER = t2.NUMBER
where t1.Value1 = 'A' and t1.Value2 = 'B' and t2.Value1 = 'B' and t2.Value2 = 'A'
```

You can check the result: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a5e7ae/1

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT NUMBER FROM MYTABLE WHERE value1 = 'A' and value2 = 'B'
INTERSECT
SELECT NUMBER FROM MYTABLE WHERE value2 = 'A' and value1 = 'B';
```

Comment: Why do you think returning only 1 and 4 would be the correct result?

Comment: @Arnab Quote from the question: "Thus for the given case my query output would be 1 and 4."

Comment: Hmm... but MySQL seems to not have `INTERSECT` syntax... and look at the 'join' tag of the question ;-)